# How to print log to file under Django Python

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and Django, so if you can provide a solution with more details and explanation that would be great.

I am using python 2.7.9, Django <1, 11, 2, u'final', 0>
I started a Django project by VS2015.
I want to print log to file.

I added the following code to `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': "./logfile",
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'WARN',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

I added the following code to `views.py`:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def hello_world(request):
    logger.error('Testing error log')
    return render(request, 'hello_world.html', {
        'current_time': str(datetime.now()),
    })
```

The **problem** is that a file named `logfile` is generated but there is nothing inside the file.
I have my project like this:[image]

Comment: is your project named 'MYAPP'? if not please replace the name with project/module name it will start working. code seems fine to me.

Comment: I changed it to `app` then it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment:

> is your project named 'MYAPP'? if not please replace the name with
>   project/module name it will start working. code seems fine to me.

Your project seems to be named `TryDjangoWebProject`, but root module is named `app` you can use that, as you have.

Comment: Thank you very much. Before I asked, I have tried `TryDjangoWebProject` but that is not working /.\ Also, the log file can be generated so I thought that may be caused by other problem.

Comment: @sflee Corrected the answer as per your comment.